# Global test hook or global test teardown for each test in robot framework

Tags: python, automated-tests, hook, robotframework

I want to some sort of hook mechanism running before/after each test.
For instance, I want to run keyword if I passed `ARGUMENT=1` to pybot or python for each test, not modifying whole bunch of tests in my project.

Is it possible?

Similar way, you can create a before or an after hook working with cucumber framework, but here. I dont understand yet.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer by myself. 
You should create new listener to use for test hooks.

About robot listeners: 
[Robot Framework Listener Interface](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#listener-version-3)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn


class global_hooks(object):
    """
        Global scope library listener 
        as global hook mechanism.
    """

    ROBOT_LISTENER_API_VERSION = 3
    ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE = "GLOBAL"

    def __init__(self):
        self.ROBOT_LIBRARY_LISTENER = self

    def __log_variables(self):
        """
            Example private function. 
        """
        if BuiltIn().get_variable_value(name='${SOME_VAR}', default=False):
            BuiltIn().run_keyword(name=self.log_test_variables.__name__)

    def end_test(self, data, result):
        """ The `end test` hook """

        self.__log_variables()

    def log_test_variables(self):
        """
            Keyword for showing up all variables in the test context.
        """

        BuiltIn().log_variables(level='INFO')
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are looking for the :
[Suite setup and Suite teardown](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#suite-setup-and-teardown)

Or maybe the [Test setup and Test teardown](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#test-setup-and-teardown)

Example of suite setup:

```
*** Settings ***
Library                         DatabaseLibrary
Force Tags                      UI  FINAL
Resource  ${CURDIR}${/}..${/}..${/}resources${/}keywords.robot
Suite setup  Run Keywords       Restore database
...                             Prepare database
Suite teardown  Run Keywords    Close All Browsers
...                             Restore database 

*** Keywords ***
Prepare database
    Connect to DB
    Execute Sql Script  ${CURDIR}${/}Setup_td.sql
    Disconnect From Database

Restore database
    Connect to DB
    Execute Sql Script  ${CURDIR}${/}Teardown_td.sql
    Disconnect From Database
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, @michel. On your answer: I should write this teardown in each test suite. I don't want to do this. I used listener interface to achieve this goal.